# How to use intergers as input and print an unrounded percentage

Tags: java, int, double, rounding, percentage

I write a program where i want to take an amount of pieces (the input data) and display the percentage relative to the input. The thing is, if i use int as data input i get rounded results. I can use double, but i don't want that the program accept decimal numbers, so only real whole numbers.

In short I want:
* The output should be like 56.34%
* The input can only be number like 5, 3, etc.

```
//Number of available tiles
static final int AVAILABLE_TILES = 64;

//Number of white pieces
out.printf("Enter the number of white pieces on the board: ");
//Input of white pieces
double whitePiecesOnBoard = in.nextDouble();

//Number of black pieces
out.printf("Enter the number of black pieces on the board: ");
//Input of black pieces
double blackPiecesOnBoard = in.nextDouble();

//Total number of pieces
double totalPieces = whitePiecesOnBoard + blackPiecesOnBoard;

//Percentage of black pieces of all pieces
double blackPiecesPercentagePieces = (blackPiecesOnBoard*100)/totalPieces;

//Percentage of black pieces of available tiles
double blackPiecesPercentageTiles = (blackPiecesOnBoard*100)/AVAILABLE_TILES;

out.printf("Black pieces %.2f%% and other pieces %.2f%%", blackPiecesPercentagePieces, blackPiecesPercentageTiles);
```

Comment: Cast one of your `int` arguments to `double` when making the calculation or make `100` `100.0` to let Java do it for you

Comment: Thanks Benjamin Urquhart, that solved my problem. I totally forgot about putting a .0 behind the 100.

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast one of your arguments to `double` while calculating the percentage. This can be done explicitly with `(double)` or implicitly by making your `100` a `100.0`:

```java
//Percentage of black pieces of all pieces
double blackPiecesPercentagePieces = (blackPiecesOnBoard*100.0)/totalPieces;

//Percentage of black pieces of available tiles
double blackPiecesPercentageTiles = (blackPiecesOnBoard*100.0)/AVAILABLE_TILES;
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson, first i didn't got the answer in this format while i already had the answer. Hence i put solved in the title